# VBScript Get Prefix of File

Tags: file, vbscript

I'm trying to parse IIS logs and depending on the prefix of the log I want to set the InputFormat of the file.

I have the log file set to a variable: logFile (i.e. C:\inetpub\logs\u_ex121004.log).

```
 Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If objFileSys.FileExists(logFile) Then
    -----Here's what I need to look for -------  If FileStartsWith "u_ex" Then
       logFormat = "W3C"
    -----Here's what I need to look for -------  Else If FileStartsWith "in" Then
       logFormat = "IIS"
    End If
 End if
```

So, what I need is a function or equivalent that will search for a string in the filename. Also, the file name is the full file name, so using Left() wouldn't work without stripping the directory path.

Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safest way to get the filename:

```
sFName = objFileSys.GetFileName(logFile)
```

then you can compare using `Left(sFName, 4) = "u_ex"` or check using `1 = Instr(sFName, "u_ex")`